# Microsoft Accelerator slower than serial implementation in C#

Tags: c#, gpu, simulation, gpgpu, accelerator

I wrote this funky little 2D N-body simulation in my spare time in C#. It worked quite well with a serial implementation, running at a good frame-rate up to about 1000 bodies at which point it started to lag.

I modified the algorithm to do the position and velocity updates in separate blocks to be run on separate cores of the CPU, and I noticed a small performance improvement.

Note that a lot of the time is spent on the actual maths, and a little time is also spent on the actual drawing of the scene.

I downloaded the Microsoft Accelerator V2 library just now and re-wrote the entire code from scratch to use that. It works as before, but it is significantly slower! Whereas before I could get almost 1000 points to run smoothly, I can now only get about 10 points under Accelerator.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/GUwEU3Kd) is my code. This is the first time I've done anything with Accelerator so it's more than likely I've botched something up.

The class is called `Test` because it was my first test. The constructor simply creates arrays of length `n` for the x- and y-positions of the bodies, their x- and y-velocities, and their masses. `dec` is just a damping factor so that round-off errors will make it implode rather than explode, and `g` is just the gravitation constant which I'm just leaving at `1.0f` for now.

`Tick()` is the function which performs all the updates. I first consider all points about any given point i, find the radius, construct a unit vector in the direction of the other points, scale that unit vector by the deceleration and gravitational constant, and then sum to a x- and y-velocity update for that point.

I then update all velocities, and all positions, and convert back to `float[]`s.

As I said, the code does technically work. The result is identical to my serial implementation except for the massive slowdown.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

I have a feeling it may be lines 85 and 86 - I'm summing together the x- and y-velocity updates for point i, and storing that into my float array, which means I need to call `Target.ToArray1D()[0]` to get the summed value.

The reason I do this is so that I have the updates for all points first, then I update the points, and then I apply the position changes based on velocity.

i.e. I don't want a situation where at time *t + 1* I update point *0* with the rest of points at time *t*, and then next update point *1* with the rest of the points again at time *t* but point 0 with the new *t + 1*. If that makes sense.

```
public void Tick()
{
    FPA fxPos = new FPA(xPos);
    FPA fyPos = new FPA(yPos);
    FPA fxVel = new FPA(xVel);
    FPA fyVel = new FPA(yVel);
    FPA fMass = new FPA(mass);

    float[] xUpd = new float[n]; // x-update for velocity
    float[] yUpd = new float[n]; // y-update for velocity

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // x- and y-pos about point i:
        FPA ixPos = PA.Subtract(fxPos, xPos[i]);
        FPA iyPos = PA.Subtract(fyPos, yPos[i]);

        // radius from point i:
        FPA iRad = PA.Sqrt(PA.Add(PA.Multiply(ixPos, ixPos), PA.Multiply(iyPos, iyPos)));

        // x- and y-pos are now unit vectors:
        ixPos = PA.Divide(ixPos, iRad);
        iyPos = PA.Divide(iyPos, iRad);

        // vectors are now scaled by mass:
        ixPos = PA.Multiply(fMass, ixPos);
        iyPos = PA.Multiply(fMass, iyPos);

        // vectors are now scaled by G and deceleration:
        ixPos = PA.Multiply(dec * g, ixPos);
        iyPos = PA.Multiply(dec * g, iyPos);

        // sum to get ith update value:
        xUpd[i] = target.ToArray1D(PA.Sum(ixPos))[0];
        yUpd[i] = target.ToArray1D(PA.Sum(iyPos))[0];
    }

    FPA fxUpd = new FPA(xUpd);
    FPA fyUpd = new FPA(yUpd);

    // update velocities:
    fxVel = PA.Add(fxUpd, fxVel);
    fyVel = PA.Add(fyUpd, fyVel);

    // update positions:
    fxPos = PA.Add(fxVel, fxPos);
    fyPos = PA.Add(fyVel, fyPos);

    xPos = target.ToArray1D(fxPos);
    yPos = target.ToArray1D(fyPos);
    xVel = target.ToArray1D(fxVel);
    yVel = target.ToArray1D(fyVel);
}
```

Comment: FYI, external links to code will seldom be looked at. Please try to condese your question & code so that all fits here on SO. If the text & code becomes too large, you need to re-consider your question.

Comment: An alternative to the posted solution is to explore alternative algorithms. For the N-Body problem in 2D, you can try using the [Quad Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) data structure to accelerate the force calculation. This brings it from `O(N^2)` to `O(N log N)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should reconsider your logic to really use parallel computing. You still working with one point at time. To use advantages of the library you should consider one action on the whole array of elements.

Comment: My serial implementation uses a double loop, since n-body is O(n²). Using the parallel library, there is a single loop. I don't think there's any way around it?